# How form widget class and we need to call ItemsList in Xcart 5.3?

Tags: x-cart

```
<widget class="XLite\Module\Tony\NewEntityDemo\View\Form\ItemsList\QuickMessage" name="list" />
<widget class="XLite\Module\Tony\NewEntityDemo\View\ItemsList\Model\QuickMessage" />
```

How to modify the above code in XCart 5.3 Template Below is my code am modify code like below but it's not pass my text box value always value save in Empty what wrong in my code How it change?

```
{% form 'XLite\\Module\\Tony\\NewEntityDemo\\View\\Form\\ItemsList\\QuickMessage' with {Classname: 'list'} %}
{{ widget('XLite\\Module\\Tony\\NewEntityDemo\\View\\ItemsList\\Model\\QuickMessage') }}
{% endform %}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? 
The example you've given is the correct Twig alternative for the Flexy code above (you can omit the ` with {Classname: 'list'}` part though).

Comment: I see that you are using the [Creating new entity and the UI for its management (Admin area)](http://devs.x-cart.com/en/basics/creating_new_entity_--_introduction_of_editable_itemslist_in_admin_area.html) guide from XC5 developer docs. Pay attention that this tutorial is outdated and fully applicable only for X-Cart 5.2 and lower. 

Check that you've correctly implemented other things, mentioned in the article. Also, template file extension should be *.twig.

Comment: P.S. If you have problems with converting Flexy templates to Twig, please try our [Flexy-to-twig converter](http://xcart.github.io/flexy-to-twig).